# Interchangeability of may and might

Tags: word-choice

For a phrase like:

> Judge Rodgers may think otherwise as might a jury

Does **may** have to come first or it's okay to interchange them?

Comment: This is mostly a question of what is idiomatic, vs what is "correct".  And that could very well differ based on what side of the pond you're on.

Comment: I think it would depend on your preference?

Comment: Yeah, but i'm sure that one of these is more common

Comment: In this case, The US may be to [blame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Light,_Star_Bright). This is actually rather a subtle question. The two nouns carry different weight wrt the importance of their thinking. And the jury's thinking is somewhat constrained by that of the judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two examples:

Firstly, “May I go to the toilet?” is a simple question, with no implications as to what the answer would be.

On the other hand, “Might I go to the toilet?” implies that the person asking expects the answer to be no.

Secondly, “This might have been a bad idea” simply brings up the thought that an idea could have been bad, without implying whether it actually was or not.

“This may have been a bad idea” instead implies that it really was a bad idea.

So overall in my opinion, the word may is a more ‘positive’ term, in that it implies that the statement in question is more likely to be true. Might is instead more ‘negative’, in that it implies that said statement is more likely to be false.

As in the examples above though, the specific implications change depending on where may/might is used. I think this depends on how formal the sentence is - A casual conversation would use may as neutral and might as negative, whereas a formal conversation would use might as neutral and may as positive.

Bear in mind that this difference is very subtle, so sometimes the words are functionally the same depending on context.

So for “Judge Rodgers may think otherwise, as might a jury”, Judge Rodgers is implied to be more likely to think otherwise, while the jury is (comparatively) less likely.

“may[...]may”, “might[...]may” and “might[...]might” would all be perfectly acceptable alternatives, but they would each carry a slight implication as to the likelihood of the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how hypothetical (subjunctive) each clause is.  They are easily reversed with the same overall meaning only by "As might a jury, the judge may think otherwise."  You are probably saying that the judge does have an opinion but you aren't sure what it is, whereas the jury in question doesn't even exist yet.